# 'Edit' and 'delete' button on visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am using the custom object for visual force page and created a custom related list for it. Now I want to place 'Edit' and 'Delete' button for each row.

How can we create the button for each row so that when we press <kbd>Edit</kbd>, the page redirects to edit page and when I press delete, the data from that row gets deleted.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: Thanks you ! 
I have used table tag and want to use command button for edit and delete.

Comment: action="{!URLFOR($Action.Junction_Data_Asset_Study__c.Edit,'aa.Id')}" is this the valid action for the command button? It is showing error as 
Error is in expression '{!URLFOR($Action.Junction_Data_Asset_Study__c.Edit,'aa.Id')}'

Comment: Please add what you tried and the errors you get

Comment: Thanks Abarisone for your reply. 
I was getting the error as "Error in expression" when i used '{!URLFOR($Action.Junction_Data_Asset_Study__c.Edit,'aa.Id')}' but i resolved it by removing the quotes from aa.id
i.e. {!URLFOR($Action.Junction_Data_Asset_Study__c.Edit,aa.Id)}'. It worked perfect for me ! :)